# Link to storage folder not working on hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

In my local project I save the images in the storage path and load normally with **asset('storage/...');**

Everything works smoothly. I do not have full access to the hosting to upload the project. only access via FTP, no ssh access. When the project is unpacked on the hosting, the storage link in the public folder brings all the files as a folder. I removed it and because I don't have ssh access I declared a route to execute the command.

```
    Route::get('storage-link', function(){
      Artisan::call('storage:link');
      echo (Artisan::output());
   });
```

When running the route, it even prints the message that it normally shows when the command is run in the console, saying that the link between the folders was created.

The problem is that the images do not load.

```
asset('/storage/cars/photo.jpg')
```

if I pass the folder to the public and call it without going through the link to the storage folder asset('/cars/photo.jpg') it shows it correctly.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand you don't get access to SSH. FTP is outdated and unsafe. That being said, the symlink should work just fine. Does it show a 404, or other status code when opening the image?

Comment: Thanks for answering, if I open the image in another tab, it shows me the error:  You don't have permission to access this resource.AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /services/users/zstorage5p2/site_url/public/storage

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.